# How to filter columns based on row condition in a Polars dataframe

Tags: python, python-polars

What is the correct way to filter (exclude columns) of a polars dataframe, based on the values within columns?
For example:

```
polars_df.std()
```

Output:

| col_1 (f64) | col_2 (f64) |
| --- | --- |
| 20242.888632 | 0.0 |

```
# now, the column with a standard deviation of 0 are to be excluded from the dataframe:
polars_df = polars_df.select(cs.numeric() != 0)
```

This results in the following:

| col_1 (bool) | col_2 (bool) |
| --- | --- |
| true | false |

This identifies the correct columns, but I want the result to be a dataframe with all columns where the standard deviation is bigger than 0. What am I missing here to get there?

Comment: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10967#issuecomment-1709916562 goes into more detail about why there is no "syntax sugar" for this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the result to be a dataframe with all columns where the standard deviation is bigger than 0

do

```py
df.select(col for col in df.iter_columns() if col.std() > 0)
```

Comment: Is this the simplest way to do that with polars? I there not a more concise way?

Comment: not that I know of

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself repeatedly needing to perform this type of operation, you can build a function that accepts a `DataFrame` and some expression (the expression should aggregate and return a boolean dtype, though no checks are performed to enforce this).

```py
from numpy.random import default_rng
import polars as pl
from polars import selectors as cs

def column_filter(df, expr):
    tmp = df.select(expr)
    if isinstance(df, pl.LazyFrame):
        tmp = tmp.collect()
    status = tmp.rows()[0]
    return pl.col(col for col, st in zip(df.columns, status) if st)

rng = default_rng(0)
df = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        rng.normal([[0, 1, 2, 3]], [[0, 1, 0, 2]], size=(100, 4)),
        schema=[*'abcd']
    )
    .with_columns(e=rng.choice([*'WXYZ'], size=100))
)


print(
    df.select(
        column_filter(df, cs.numeric().std() > 0),
        pl.col('e'),
    ),
    sep='\n',
)
# shape: (100, 3)
# ┌───────────┬──────────┬─────┐
# │ b         ┆ d        ┆ e   │
# │ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ --- │
# │ f64       ┆ f64      ┆ str │
# ╞═══════════╪══════════╪═════╡
# │ 0.867895  ┆ 3.2098   ┆ X   │
# │ 1.361595  ┆ 4.894162 ┆ W   │
# │ -0.265421 ┆ 3.082652 ┆ Z   │
# │ 0.781208  ┆ 1.535465 ┆ Y   │
# │ …         ┆ …        ┆ …   │
# │ 0.512782  ┆ 1.759142 ┆ W   │
# │ 1.367466  ┆ 2.039108 ┆ Z   │
# │ 0.418967  ┆ 3.178112 ┆ Z   │
# │ -0.095472 ┆ 3.887983 ┆ X   │
# └───────────┴──────────┴─────┘
```

This has the benefit of returning the filtered columns as an expression so that you can operate on subsets and recombine data as needed.